# Html lost in POST request

Tags: javascript, html, post

I try to send an object, containing an object that contains raw html

```
template: "<div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_84909"><div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12"><h1 class="padding10">Big title</h1></div></div></div><div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_46417"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h2 class="padding10">Middle title</h2></div></div></div><div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_20274"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h3 class="padding10">Small title</h3></div></div></div>"
```

I send it like this :

```
action.addCampaign = function(idLieu, campaign){
        console.log("Campaign : ", campaign);
        return  $http({
            url: $company.backend+'/lieu/'+idLieu+'/campaign', 
            method: 'POST',
            data: $.param(campaign),
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
    }
```

When I display what the server received, I notice that the object containing html is null

Can someone tell me why ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: wrap your html with (') single qoute.

Answer (score 4):

You have some quotes issue;
You can either replace the ones around the javascript string with single quotes.
Or escape every double-quote inside your string.

```
template: '<div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_84909"><div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12"><h1 class="padding10">Big title</h1></div></div></div><div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_46417"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h2 class="padding10">Middle title</h2></div></div></div><div class="dd_snippet" id="snippet_20274"><div class="row"><div class="col-xs-12"><h3 class="padding10">Small title</h3></div></div></div>'
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't put double quotes. I just collect the html from a part of my page. And I'm trying to save. And I use it  within an other context, it works.

Comment: Then the problem might be "the way you collect HTML" ? Can you post more code ?

Comment: Thanks taking time to answer me, I found an another solution. To anwser to your comment, it's not the way I collect the  HTML; please consider, the console.log(campaign), I see exactly what I wanted to collect in template obbject.